# Full-width image inside container in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width, padding

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have a template layout with

```
<div class="navbar">
  ...
</div>
<div class="container">
  {{content}}
</div>
```

This works in almost all cases. However, sometimes I want an image in the content to take up the full width, but this is not possible due to the `.container` which uses `left-padding` and `right-padding`.

I could solve this by adding the `.container` class in each view at the right places instead of in my template layout file, but this will become quite annoying. Especially if I have a CMS where different authors can write articles, and if they want a full-width image in the middle of their article, they have to write raw html to be something like

```
<div class="container">
  some text
</div>
<div class="full-width-image">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="container">
  more text
</div>
..
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using `container-fluid`?

Comment: No, I am not. But I just read that if I use `<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row">no padding</div></div>`, I could maybe obtain what I want. Why is this behaviour not in the `.container` class :(

Comment: `container` is meant for a fixed width layout, `container-fluid` is for full width.

Answer (score 25):

you can use `vw` units with negative margin. And it's responsive friendly.

```
.full-width-image {
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;  
   margin-left: -50vw;
}

.full-width-image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ondrejruzicka/07y0o746/

Comment: Nice one! I would also add a "max-width: 100vw;" as some conflicting css with this property set would otherwise mess it up.

Comment: For using _full-width-image_ like image class add _height: auto_.

Comment: I just try this solution and it has a problem. If you have scroll bar, the calculations get messy and a horizontal scroll bar is added. See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ondrejruzicka/07y0o746/
I change the `left: 50%;`to be `left: 49%` but that's very ugly solution... do you guys know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In **bootstrap 4**, you can apply `img-fluid` class:

```
<img class="img-fluid w-100" src="path.jpg" />
```

Here `w-100` class is applied to ensure smaller images to fit to it's container.

For those who are using **bootstrap 3**: Just apply `img-responsive` instead of `img-fluid`.

Comment: in my case, without w-100 it was not fit on the larger screens, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

As a simple solution that doesn't require any css, you can use a px-0 spacing utility to set the image to full width.

```
<!-- FULL-WIDTH IMAGE --> 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 px-0">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="your-image">
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<!-- 12 COLUMN IMAGE --> 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="your-image">
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

see this code pen:

See the Pen [full width image](https://codepen.io/fdhu/pen/XYJWyj/) by ferdinand huber ([@fdhu](https://codepen.io/fdhu)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

more about spacing utilities:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 2):

I just have the feeling that this one could help you. What I did was make the image as the background to the `<div>` itself and set the specified height to have the image visible since there are no contents inside.

**CSS**

```
.full-width-image {
  height: 300px; // your specified height
  background: url("your-image.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Plus to have it the left and right padding to align with your other contents add the class `.container`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container full-width-image"></div>
```

Here's a sample [demo](http://jsbin.com/defosasibi/edit?output) of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `padding` of `div.container` you could set a negative `margin` of the same amount on your image class.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="full-width-image" src="whatever.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.full-width-image {
    margin: -10px;
}
```

Alternatively, and probably more correctly, you could remove the `padding` from `div.container` entirely and only add it to the elements within it that need it.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the negative margin. But with Bootstrap it's harder to get the exact margin each time because of several breakpoints and different devices.

This is the Javascript you can add. What it does is actually wraps all your images into a figure with the class "image-centered" and **compares the initial width of the image (must be set as an HTML attribute) with the width it has to take due to screen constraints.** If the initial image width is higher than the screen constraints, the image inside your articles will be full-screen. Otherwise it will be centered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").wrap("<figure class='image-centered'></figure>");
    $("figure.image-centered").each(function(){
        if ($(this).children("img").attr("width") > $(this).children("img").width()){
            var containerMargins = $(".container").css("marginRight").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
            var containerPadding = $(".container").css("paddingRight").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
            var calc = $(".container").width() + (Number(containerMargins) + Number(containerPadding))*2;
            $(this).css({"maxWidth": `${calc}px`, "margin": `1em -${Number(containerMargins) + Number(containerPadding)}px`});
        }
    });
});
```

And CSS:

```
img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
    max-width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

figure {
    margin: 1em 0; 
}
figure.image-centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `container-fluid` class instead of `container` to bring the background image to responsive full width.

Example html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">   
        <div class="row image1">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.image1{
background-image:url("path_to_image.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 400px;
min-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: He knows that, but then he needs to use .container and after it .container-fluid and then .container again and so on. A lot of work by adding .container all the time instead of having it as default and just selecting what's fluid afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
    <div class="alignfull">
                          
         <img class="img-fluid" style="background-size: cover;
                                       background-position: center ; 
                                       background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                       height: auto;
                                       min-width: 100%; 
                                       width: -moz-available; " 
         src="{{ $image->image }}" alt="An image">

   </div>
```